# Error installing Google chrome on debian linux

Tags: google-chrome

I am getting the following error when I try to install Google chrome on debian linux -

```
Google-chrome-stable depends on libnspr4-0d (>= 4.7.3-0ubuntu1~) | libnspr4 (>= 4.8.7-0ubuntu1); however:
  Version of libnspr4-0d on system is 4.7.1-5.
  Package libnspr4 is not installed.
```

So to install libnspr4 I tried sudo apt-get install libnspr4 and I get this error -

> Package libnspr4 is not available, but is referred to by another
>   package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been
>   obsoleted, or is only available from another source E: Package
>   libnspr4 has no installation candidate

How do I proceed from here?

Answer (score 1):

See if `chromium-browser` is in your repo (apt-cache search chromium-browser). If so, that's what you want.

Comment: Hi GGG, thanks for pointing me in the right direction ... yes i was missing chrome in my  repo ... did that and it worked ... here are the steps i followed ... 1. wget -q -O – https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -

2. apt-get update

3. emacs /etc/apt/sources.list

# Google software repository
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/deb/ stable non-free main

4. sudo apt-get update

5. sudo apt-get install google-chrome-unstable

Comment: @Rivlin I'd still recommend [Chromium](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=chromium-browser) over Chrome.